# Regular Expression: Search key validation

Tags: c#, regex

Please help with the regular expression. I am working on validating a string. The value should not contain only % and if there is a % the length should be more than 3 characters including %. % can be anywhere in the string (dot is included).

I could come up with this. This validation should only happen when % is in the string. If there is no % no validation is necessary.

`@"^[a-zA-Z0-9'.]*%"; //{3,}$";`

Thanks, Naveen

Examples:

- `"%"` - Fail
- `"%12"` - Fail
- `"%123"` - Pass
- `"%1234"` - Pass
- `"12%3"` - Pass
- `"abc%"` - Pass
- `"abc"` - Pass
- `"A"` - Pass
- `"ABC"` - Pass

Comment: Validation a string if it contains %, if yes then length of the string should be greater than 3.

Comment: Recommend using http://www.regexplained.co.uk/ to check the regex.

Comment: What about "%%%%" - pass or fail?

Comment: Fail, sorry didn't gave this in an example.

Comment: Thank you all for the Answers and suggestion. As per King and Jay, would try to keep the solution simple. Thank you John, this was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this needs `Regex` to solve, just some string methods are OK:

```
var valid = !input.Contains("%") || input.Length > 3;
```

If you want to use `Regex`, here you are:

```
^([^%]+|.{4,})$
```

Comment: Yes true, other validations are done using regular expression attribute, so trying to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, but it is better to use the right tool for the job than to use the wrong tool and be consistent.

Answer (score 6):

If that is the extent of your validation, you'd be better off using `Contains("%")` and `Length` property of the `string`.

```
return !value.Contains("%") || value.Length > 3;
```

It is inherently difficult with a single regular expression to test for *both* total length and for a pattern within. If the `%` were at a fixed location (beginning, end, 2rd character from the start, etc.), it would fit better, but as-is, this is not a problem to be solved *gracefully* with a single RegEx.

It could be done with an ugly RegEx, using some lookarounds, but that solution is not likely to be portable across different RegEx implementations (for example, it probably wouldn't work with client-side Javascript validation).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression in c#:

```
@"^((?=(?>.*?[^%]){3,}).*|[^%]+)$"
```

It matches as described in your examples:

- `"%"` - Fail
- `"%12"` - Fail
- `"%123"` - Pass
- `"%1234"` - Pass
- `"12%3"` - Pass
- `"abc%"` - Pass
- `"abc"` - Pass
- `"A"` - Pass
- `"ABC"` - Pass

Use a non capturing, non atomic group in the same expression for it to work in javascript (addresses Jay's issue):

```
@"^((?=(?:.*?[^%]){3,}).*|[^%]+)$"
```

Comment: @Jay Beauty is in the eye of the beholder ;)

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that at least 1 character is needed for validation -

```
 ^(?:[^%]+|.*[^%].*[^%].*[^%].*)$
```

Same as JonM (don't know how to delete this though).